# UI that feels native for PhoneGap Application on iOS

Tags: ios, mobile, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am in the process of planning the development of an iPad application and we will be using PhoneGap to develop the app.  I have been looking around for a UI solution that feels native and was hoping some Stackoverflowers could lend some insight on their experience. I have used jQTouch and jQuerymbobile and I do not feel they are fitting for this project, I would like something that feels native (speed and interaction) but is also easily skinnable with the web technologies I know and trust.

Comment: "feels native (speed and interaction)" is the major drawback of webapps, I don't think you'll achieve any of that unless it's a true native app

Comment: I think with effort JQuery Mobile and Sencha are the most powerful, another framework is Dojo. Where do you have lacks in speed and interaction? Sometimes it is only specific areas where it lacks, such as scroll behavior (and for this, there are solutions).

Comment: Thanks @Leon & Zyrex.  I feel like I have used applications that feel really close but are not native.  The best case is really what I am looking for as developing native is not really an option.  Zyrex - How do you feel the learning curve is with Dojo?  I have heard good things about DoJo in regards to WebApps but have not really dug around too much.

Answer (score 1):

[Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch) and [Titaniam Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) come to my mind. Some learning curve for each but if you are going for the closest native iOS feel these are the 2 that I've found to match the closest.

I have had experience with Sencha Touch myself. From a web developer's point of view, once you get past the initial shock of initially building everything with JavaScript, you can then tweak your css and insert html here and there as needed. Which is nice since you are  using the skills you already have as a web dev.

In my early research I was turned off of Titanium mainly due to its pricing structure for what we were going to user it for; however, it did boast the possibility to compile into native code, as I recall.

Both are worth looking in to, but I should add that going native by far offers the most flexibility and power in my humble opinion, assuming you are willing to learn objective-C.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Todd, Sencha Touch was the direction I was leaning in as the other tools I have used just have not felt right enough.  I am totally willing to learn objective-C but improving the technologies I am already somewhat proficient in seems like a better move rather than learning something I may not be active in practice with.  +1

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap has native [iPhone plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/NativeControls). And even though phonegap app runs inside webview you can customise app look and feel like native.

Now the only real problem is responsiveness, since if you're using jQuery Mobile, but there are lots of tips on optimisation.